# Running ExecutorService inside scheduled method

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, executorservice

I've got a question about thread pools of executors, runninng one inside another.

Let's say I've got Spring service with scheduled method and other service creates ExecutorService and runs some action method

```
@Service
public class ScheduledService
{

    @Autowired
    WorkService workService;

    @Scheduled(cron = "1 * * * * * ")
    public void method() {
        workService.execute();

    }
}

@Service
public class WorkService {

    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

    public void execute() {
        executorService.submit(()->action());
    }

    private void action() {
        //some action
    }
}
```

As I know, by default pool size for @Scheduled is 1. Inside thread from this pool i'm trying to create new executorService with larger pool.

So question is - how executions will be spread over CPU cores, will executor service really work in parallel? I've got a feeling, that it doesn't. I tried to run the same job on 2 vCores and 4 vCores machine and execution time is the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How it is spread over CPU cores depends also of how the operating system is busy, but let's say nothing else happen, each CPU core is able to execute one thread. If there are more active threads than CPU cores, the operating system is responsible for dispatching CPU time among the threads.

On your example, one thread will execute the @Scheduled method, which is quite fast because it does not do much, just submit a new action to the executor service.

Then the executor service, which has up to 20 threads, will execute the action on the first available thread among the 20.

So the answer is yes, the actions will be done in parallel.

You can try by scheduling very often your method, let's say every second:

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "* * * ? * *")
```

Then do something longer than 1 second in your action (else the action will finish before the next schedule). You will see actions doing the job in parallel.

By the way, why not to use a ScheduledExecutorService ? Or configure spring to use several threads ?

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, i've added some logging to print out thread names, it works in parallel. About ScheduledExecutorService - in real code the logic is more complicated. Scheduled servcie polling queue for new messages, if it receives a message - it starts processing, and only in one of the parts of processing I can do stuff in parallel.